# How To Populate Foreign Key by Comparing Columns in Two Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Table A is an inventory of items imported from a CSV file. The spreadsheet included a column for location of inventory items (i.e., toothbrush, bathroom).

Table B is a list of all the distinct locations from Table A.

I now want to update table A with the ID from Table B, in a new column in Table A set up as a foreign key. I need each record in Table A to have a `location_id` where the text of `location` matches `as_entered` in Table B.

I have tried:

```
UPDATE imported_data_copy
SET imported_data_copy.location_id=locations.id
WHERE locations.as_entered LIKE imported_data_copy.location;
```

The error I get is:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'locations.as_entered' in 'where clause'
```

There is, in fact, an `as_entered` column in the locations table.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are doing a `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE` operation on a particular table in `WHERE` clause the left had side is always your reference of the target table. So in this case `imported_data_copy.location` is your target column and should be on left hand side. This is a bit different from a logical or mathematical operation so which side you have your column matters.

```
UPDATE imported_data_copy, locations
SET imported_data_copy.location_id=locations.id
WHERE imported_data_copy.location LIKE locations.as_entered;
```

On another note for you design, if you refer a table with id using text is not a best practice. Using integer columns for ID is much better than text unless you have a good (very good) reason.

Comment: locations.id is an integer. Replacing the text with the integer is precisely what I'm trying to do. First step was to create a new table with the locations in it, the next step is to put the location id's into the items table, and lastly, remove the text column from the import table.

Just tried your revised query and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @KevinWixson Sorry I was away, did you manage to fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be that I did not include the `locations` table in the UPDATE clause. The correct syntax turned out to be:

```
UPDATE imported_data_copy,locations
SET imported_data_copy.location_id=locations.id 
WHERE imported_data_copy.location LIKE locations.as_entered;
```

Glad I asked here, though, because I would still have had trouble with `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` clause is backwards, it should be `WHERE imported_data_copy.location LIKE locations.as_entered`